# A fundamental question about crossover distortion

Tags: transistors, amplifier, bjt, ltspice, distortion

Following shows the input output waveforms to illustrate crossover distortion:

[image]

The supply rails are indicated as if it is a dual supply(+V & -V).

I then tried to simulate this in LTspice as in the below simulation:

[image]

As you see above there is no distortion seen in the output voltage.

Am I mistaken that crossover distortion only happens when using single supply, or is my simulation wrong since it doesn't reveal any sort of distortion at the output?

Comment: Diode voltage with 1 mA load is 600 mV. You have no load and insufficient V. With negative feedback and sufficient excess gain, this can be eliminated.

Comment: Look at the emitter and collector connections on your PNP transistor.

Comment: @Colin good spot - I had assumed he transcribed the circuit correctly but it just goes to show how much attention to detail is actually required when designing electronic stuff.

Comment: I guess it doesn't matter fort this question; base emitter and base collector junctions are very similar. So even I correct still it doesn't produce distortion as in the question. Andy aka's remedy still needed. But thanks for the catch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Am I mistaken that crossover distortion only happens when using single
>   supply?

Yes you are mistaken.

> Or is my simulation wrong since it doesn't reveal any sort of
>   distortion at the output?

You need to add a load to the output to be able to recognize cross over distortion. Make sure your input voltage is several volts p-p too.

```
@Colin spotted the other mistake - Q2 is connected incorrectly.
```

It will work somewhat with C and E reversed but not as well.

Comment: Alright it worked now.

Answer (score 1):

In your diagram you show a speaker connected to the output as load but in your simulation you have not included the load at the output.

This is known as a class B amplifier. You can also use a coupling capacitor at the input to improve the circuit.

This is much more efficient at around 50% then a class A amplifier, however now you will encounter cross over distortion.

To get an increase in efficiency of atleast 60% and to eliminate cross over distortion have a look at the class AB amplifier which is a combination of the class A amplifier and the class B amplifier.